# Prestashop 1.7.7.5 installation into Ubuntu 20.04 with nginx

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, installation, prestashop

I really need help on installing Prestashop 1.7.7.5 on my ubuntu server with nginx and php7.3, On my local server installation is complete and works perfectly but it was in Xampp with apache. I have tried lots of tutorials but they are not working. Problem is during the installation error occurs at 67% when installing addons module; Error Http -500;

Comment: error http -500 says very little try to look into logs maybe there will be more detailed description what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need  to modify the max_execution_time value in php.ini by default is 30 (second) I think, put an higher value and restart server, while the process install the addond modules, it take to long time over the default value.

Comment: Make sure your Ubuntu server have proper outgoing connection to the **prestashop.com** domain, some API requests are performed during installation and can slow down the whole process..